Two spheres at the bottom right corner 3D viewport
The 2 spheres at the bottom right corner in 3d viewport look like this on my blender, while in many tutorials they are the other way round. My question is will that effect anything and is there a way to make them be like they should?


It looks as if the developers have swapped them round between Blender 3.6 and 4.2. It shouldn't make the slightest difference.
